# Check if page needs enabled flash player. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, popup, cross-browser

I have a bunch of online games and a two of them to load need a flash player enabled. I want to show a notification when: 
the game needs a flush, and a user has a disabled flush on his browser.

So there are 2 conditions. I already know how to detect when the user has disabled flash but how to detect which game/website needs flash to load? 
Is there a way to do this with JavaScript? Or that info I should get from a game provider?

Comment: _“Is there a way to do this with JavaScript?”_ - that depends very much on how you embed these games to begin with. If all you do is load stuff from a different domain into an iframe for example, then you have no JS access to this at all from your end. But even in other scenarios, there’s still probably lots of different ways how exactly those games could “use flash”, figuring that out via JS is likely going to be anywhere between very difficult and impossible.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I have a bunch of online games ... how to detect which game/website needs flash to load?"*

A Flash game is saved as an `.swf` file.
 If you're using that file type in a browser then it'll need the Flash plugin to load correctly.

For a website needing Flash plugin, you could check its page source code for any references to some `.swf` inside an `<embed>` or `<object>` tag. Also check source for text like `SWFObject` (since SWFObject is sometimes used by websites to embed Flash content).